# Copy Rows from another sheet into a new sheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using `apache poi` and what I want to do is:

[image]

I have a sheet which looks like that and I want to process the rows which have a certain name to another sheets like that:

[image]           [image]

For this operation I have written some lines of code:

```
public void read() throws Exception {
    InputStream inp = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
    System.out.println(inputFile);
    // InputStream inp = new FileInputStream("workbook.xlsx");

    wb = WorkbookFactory.create(inp);

    Sheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(0);

    // 1. get the Name Values in an array list
    for (Row r : sheet) {
        Cell c = r.getCell(4);
        c.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);
        if (c != null) {
            nameList.add(c.getStringCellValue());
        }
    }

    // 2. Remove the duplicates
    removeDuplicates(nameList);

    for (Row r : sheet) {
        Cell c = r.getCell(4);
        c.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING);

        //Create new workbook
        Workbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        for (int i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++) {

            //if the list with the name equals the cell in the excel sheet
            if (nameList.get(i).equals(c.toString())) {

                // Output path
                fileOut = new FileOutputStream(
                        "C:/Users/Desktop/"
                                + nameList.get(i) + ".xls");

                // 3. create workbook and sheet
                worksheet = workbook.createSheet(nameList.get(i));

                //TODO Problem: How to get the rows from the other sheet?

                System.out.println("Write out Sheet: " + nameList.get(i));
            }
        }

        workbook.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am struggeling with the `getting the rows from the other sheet part`. I really would appreciate your answers on how to implement that?

Comment: Are you getting any error or its not just getting as you expect ?

Comment: @SachinThapa Nope not yet. But I am struggeling with the solution to get all the rows from the other sheet...